# How to express our feeling after giving something to someone who is desperately looking for?

Tags: synonyms

How to express our feeling after giving something to someone who is desperately looking for?

For example, a person is looking for a feature in my software application, and I implemented it and given to him to use after a long time of waiting. Now the user feels happy, but how to express my feeling? What is the correct word for my feeling.

Comment: Only _you_ can know what that feeling is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Self-gratified*, in the sense that it makes you feel good about yourself, is one word for how you may feel after doing something that pleases someone else.

But how and why human beings are altruistic, at least some of the time, has been studied by experts in different fields. It’s complicated. So there’s no single word that captures how people feel about doing something helpful or beneficial to someone else.

The Wikipedia article Altruism explores some of this research.